# Unpredicatble stub initialization in spock

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock, stub

This is a sample spock spec method (I know it doesn't make sense to test what stub is returning, this is a simplification for this question purpose only):

```
def "my test"() {
   given: 
   var upload = Mock(Upload){
       waitForCompletion() >> { throw new InterruptedException() }
   }

   var transferManager = Mock(TransferManager) {
       upload(_,_,_) >> upload
   }
   
   when: 
   var up = transferManager.upload(null, null, null)
   up.waitForCompletion()  
   
   then:
   thrown(InterruptedException) 
}
```

I assume that the test is quite straightforward and it should pass, but it gives me:

```
Expected exception of type 'java.lang.InterruptedException', but got 'java.lang.NullPointerException'
```

Basically, *transferManager.upload()* returns the default null instead of configured *upload* mock.

Now, if I change transferManager initialization to this:

```
   var transferManager = Mock(TransferManager)
   transferManager.upload(_,_,_) >> upload
```

It starts to work as expected.
It seems to me that the problem exists only when stub uses another stub. For example, when using upload stub directly:

```
when:
upload.waitForCompletion()
```

it works as expected (it passes).

Also when I change *transferManager* initialization so that it doesn't use another stub:

```
var transferManager = Mock(TransferManager) {
    throw new InterruptedException()
}
```

the test also passes.

So my question is, why this works as expected:

```
   var transferManager = Mock(TransferManager)
   transferManager.upload(_,_,_) >> upload
```

while that doesn't set up upload method properly:

```
   var transferManager = Mock(TransferManager) {
       upload(_,_,_) >> upload
   }
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused because you named the variable `upload` which is the same name as the method you want to call on `TransferManager`.

```
var upload = Mock(Upload){
  waitForCompletion() >> { throw new InterruptedException() }
}

var transferManager = Mock(TransferManager) {
  upload(_,_,_) >> upload
}
```

In this case the local variable has a higher precedence over the delegation of the closure, which is why things go awry.
I don't think there is much we can do on the Spock side as this how groovy works.

```
def upload = new Upload()
def transferManager = new TransferManager()
transferManager.with {
  upload("a", "b", "c")
}
```

will fail with `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Upload.call() is applicable for argument types: (String, String, String) values: [a, b, c]`

The easiest way to fix the example, is to rename the variable to something non-conflicting. Alternatively, you can prefix the stubbing with it. to make it unambiguous.

Comment: Leonard, do you see any chance to have Spock issue some kind of warning in this case?

Comment: Maybe, it is possible but Spock hasn't done any warnings so far, only compile errors. This might be better suited to CodeNarc or Intellij inspections.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA has no inspection for it. CodeNarc, I do not even know. I think that stuff like that is tricky to dectect by users, and relying on extra IDE or build tools to catch that problem - if such tools even exist - is of course an easy way out for the Spock team. I am not a Groovy buff, but a fairly experienced Spock user, and I did not see it. So I guess, most other Spock will not notice either, especially given the fact that the NPE is not helpful. It is utterly non-intuitive, but during Spock's AST there would be a chance to catch this or similar cases.

Comment: Having gotten curious, I installed the CodeNarc plugin in IDEA. Lots of inspections there, but none fitting this requirement. I guess, it is too much of a Spock-ism (with regard to the usage pattern for its DSL), even though it simply utilises Groovy syntax, of course.

Comment: I only meant that this would be the right place to put the warning/inspection, not that there is already one.

Comment: We do not have to agree on everything. So I choose to disagree. But talk is cheap for me, you would have to carry the burden of implementing it in Spock. So, of course I understand that you need to prioritise and this one will not make it into the backlog. Thanks again for answering the question and helping to correct my oversight. 

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Good catch, I think you found a bug.</strike>

**Update:** My answer is plain wrong, please disregard it. Leonard is absolutely right (and I am stupid and ugly), I overlooked the naming issue.

I am assuming you use Spock 2.0 and a Java 10+ JDK, because I see `var` instead of `def` in your specification. But the result is the same with `def`, even on Spock 1.3 and Groovy 2.5.

I created an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Spock issue #1351](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/1351) on your behalf.

Comment: OK, thanks fir the input. Yes, I use Spock 2.0 and JDK 11

Comment: Does it still fail if the first mock variable is not called `upload`?